# How to install pycocotools on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, python-3.7, pycocotools

I am trying to install pycocotools on Windows 10. I used this command:

pip install git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#egg=pycocotools^&subdirectory=PythonAPI

You can see the error output in the following picture:

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: If you use windows. Try download from [https://pypi.org/project/pycocotools-windows/#files](https://pypi.org/project/pycocotools-windows/#files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows building of some COCO tools gave me a bit of a headache too, I finnaly translated decode mask function for the Windows version of my code.

https://github.com/armengot/COCO_decode_mask/tree/main/python

In Linux any problems.